# how to update the pre-trained word2vec model with new train data using genism

Tags: python, deep-learning, word2vec, gensim

Hi I have used the genism to load the Spanish  fasttext word2vec model with following code:

```
Word2Vec = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('../data/raw/wiki.es.vec',
                                             binary=False)
```

and now I want to train the word2vec with new training sentences.

I know that in the genism can use the following code to train new sentences if the model is loaded:

```
 model.build_vocab(sentences)  # prepare the model vocabulary
 model.train(sentences, )
```

But how to update the model if I used the `KeyedVectors.load_word2vec` to load the model.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use keyedvectors for resuming training as per [Gensim documentation](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/keyedvectors.html). You will need to save the full model in previous training run to allow resuming training. Keyedvectors remove training related information and other metadata to reduce memory footprint.